# Clear the dirent cache on Linux

Tags: find

Watch the difference:

```
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/stuff/nana$ time find . -name libnana.a
./libnana.a

real    0m0.215s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.017s
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/stuff/nana$ time find . -name libnana.a
./libnana.a

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.004s
ryan@DevPC-LX:~/stuff/nana$
```

A quick Google found [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/dcache.h), which shows that there is a cache for `dirent`. The question: how do I clear it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

Comment: or you can run `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, also i believe it's best to close firefox before running this command if you are using `profile-sync-deamon`